# Binary Tree insertion program

Tags: binary-tree

70, 1 , 1, 6, 5, 8, 5, 9, 4, 10, 8, 40, 58, 2, 0, 6, 91, 45, 66, 10, 66, 6, 42, 30, 25, 20, 16, 11, 19

Using the numbers above, create a program that will display the tree structure once all the numbers are inserted.

example:

```
--------------------------------70--------------------------------
--------------------1---------------------1-----------------------
------------6-------------5------------8---------5----------------
```

Im having trouble comprehending how thisi s done

Comment: If your "numbers" are an array representation of a binary tree, as you are showing, then you just need to display - there is no insertion going on. If you need to do insertion, then your example is likely wrong (usually "binary tree insertion" implies ordering a heap). What is your question? And what, exactly, are you having trouble comprehending?

Answer (score 0):

70 is the root node

1 and 1 and the second level node, they both depend of 70

6, 5, 8, 5 are the third level node, 6 and 5 depend of the first 1, 8 and 5 depend of the second 1

then on the fourth level, 9 and 4 depend of 6

etc